# building flutter demo app failure with andriod emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

device : Macbook pro catalina and all softwares are up to date .

I did all the correct steps for setting up flutter in android studio , installing the recommended emulator , every thing is ok but building flutter demo app didnt work in emulator (it was worked perfectly in IOS simulator) and showed this error :

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.

  > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   /Users/heshamayman/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/core-lambda-stubs.jar
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 39s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

The error you are facing might be due to partial installation of SDK on your device.

Here, how you may be able to fix it.

First Navigate to **/Users/heshamayman/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/** using finder.(CAN BE HIDDEN IN CASE PRESS [command+shift+.] TO SHOW HIDDEN FILE IN FINDER)

Then delete the folder 28.0.3

After DELETING:

In Android Studio:

[GO TO TOOLS -> SDK MANAGER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1mOI.jpg)
[SELECT SDK Tools -> Show Package Details -> select 28.0.3 (assuming it got deleted on first place).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfvHf.png)

This worked for me. Hope this will work for you also. :D